# Образование существительного

Tags: словообразование

Какое из этих существительных имеет необычное происхождение, образовалось с участием формы родительного падежа и хранит в своей основе часть бывшего окончания?
А) пролог
Б) итог
В) демагог
Г) порог
Д) слог

Comment: У-у-у, надо лезть в словарь, смотреть откуда (от каких слов) эти слова произошли...  Как это называется?  Этимология?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итог - возникло в XVIII веке на основе "итого, и того", окончание ОГО. В основу слова "итог" входит часть окончания "ОГ".

Comment: Vera, у Вас никакой жалости к бедным студентам не осталось?  Помните поговорку: "дай человеку рыбу..., научи человека рыбу ловить..."?

Comment: Victor Bazarov, кто ж виноват, что у Веры есть удочка, а у вас - только поговорка?